# What would the job title be for someone who reconstructs and creates documents with LaTeX, InDesign, and FineReader Pro?

Tags: discussion

I've been looking through the BLS (Bureau of Labor Statistics) site, and I've not been able to find a job that matches up with these duties:

- Creates accessible documentation and documents (with LaTeX, InDesign, and RoboHelp)
- Digitizes documents and ensures that they are accessible (Uses FineReader Pro and other OCR/ICR tools)
- Proofreads and edits copy

Is this a 'documentation specialist'? A 'technical writer'? A 'digital document specialist'?

Comment: Sorry, but this is off-topic here (not about TeX-sx) and for the main site (not about TeX or related subjects).